# Filtering by Timestamp with PostgreSQL's CTE not working

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have multiple prices for each `locl_ntwrk_id`.

What I am trying to accomplish is select only **ONE** price with `gateway.pricings.charges.t_valid <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)`.

However I am currently unable to get anything.

---

Table locales.countries:

```
+--------------+--------------+
|locl_ctry_id  |icc           |
+--------------+--------------+    
|218           |387           |
|219           |385           |
|220           |381           |
|297           |382           |
+--------------+--------------+
```

Table locales.networks:

```
+--------------+--------------+
|locl_ntwrk_id |locl_ctry_id  |
+--------------+--------------+
|21890         |218           |
|21805         |218           |
|21803         |218           |
|21910         |219           |
|21902         |219           |
|21901         |219           |
|21912         |219           |
+--------------+--------------+
```

And table pricings.charges:

```
+--------------+---------------------------+--------------+--------------+
|locl_ntwrk_id |t_valid                    |locl_ccy_id   |cost          |
+--------------+---------------------------+--------------+--------------+
|21890         |2017-02-06 00:00:00.000000 |978           |1.0           |
|21890         |2019-04-01 00:00:00.000000 |978           |2.0           |
|21805         |2019-04-01 00:00:00.000000 |978           |2.0           |
|21805         |2017-02-06 00:00:00.000000 |978           |1.0           |
|21803         |2017-02-06 00:00:00.000000 |978           |1.0           |
+--------------+---------------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

My SQL:

```
WITH cte_pricings AS (
   SELECT 
      gateway.pricings.charges.locl_ntwrk_id, 
      gateway.pricings.charges.t_valid, 
      gateway.pricings.charges.locl_ccy_id, 
      gateway.pricings.charges.cost

   FROM gateway.pricings.charges

   WHERE gateway.pricings.charges.t_valid <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) 
)
   SELECT
      gateway.locales.countries.locl_ctry_id, 
      gateway.locales.countries.icc,
      gateway.locales.networks.locl_ntwrk_id,
      gateway.locales.networks.locl_ctry_id

   FROM gateway.locales.countries

   LEFT JOIN gateway.locales.networks USING (locl_ctry_id)

   LEFT JOIN cte_pricings USING (locl_ntwrk_id);

   WHERE left(gateway.locales.countries.icc::text, 2) IN ('38')
```

Expected outcome if `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is  2019-04-02:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------------+--------------+--------------+
|locl_ctry_id  |icc           |locl_ntwrk_id |t_valid                    |locl_ccy_id   |cost          |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------------+--------------+--------------+
|218           |387           |21890         |2019-04-01 00:00:00.000000 |978           |2.0           |
|218           |387           |21805         |2019-04-01 00:00:00.000000 |978           |2.0           |
|218           |387           |21803         |2017-02-06 00:00:00.000000 |978           |1.0           |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Expected outcome if `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` is  2019-03-20:

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------------+--------------+--------------+
|locl_ctry_id  |icc           |locl_ntwrk_id |t_valid                    |locl_ccy_id   |cost          |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------------+--------------+--------------+
|218           |387           |21890         |2017-02-06 00:00:00.000000 |978           |1.0           |
|218           |387           |21805         |2017-02-06 00:00:00.000000 |978           |1.0           |
|218           |387           |21803         |2017-02-06 00:00:00.000000 |978           |1.0           |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+---------------------------+--------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `distinct on`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (locl_ctry_id, icc, locl_ntwrk_id) . . .
FROM gateway.locales.countries c JOIN
     gateway.locales.networks
     USING (locl_ctry_id) JOIN
     gateway.pricings.charges ch
     USING (locl_ntwrk_id)
WHERE ch.t_valid <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
ORDER BY locl_ctry_id, icc, locl_ntwrk_id, ch.t_valid DESC
```

Comment: Get a syntax error, at or near FROM. Not familiar with `distinct`. `SELECT DISTINCT ON (
    gateway.locales.countries.locl_ctry_id,
    gateway.locales.countries.icc,
    gateway.locales.networks.locl_ntwrk_id,
    gateway.locales.networks.locl_ctry_id,
    gateway.locales.countries.locl_ctry_id
)
FROM gateway.locales.countries c

JOIN gateway.locales.networks USING (locl_ctry_id)
JOIN gateway.pricings.charges ch USING (locl_ntwrk_id)

WHERE ch.t_valid <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6)
ORDER BY locl_ctry_id, icc, locl_ntwrk_id, ch.t_valid DESC`

Comment: @Borsn . . . The columns that you want to select go where the `. . .` is.  That is after the closing parent for `distinct on`.